# Adding equation plugin on TinyMCE or CKEditor on Angular 4 ngx-admin platform

Tags: angular, ckeditor, tinymce

I am trying to integrate an equation plugin (like 'formula' or 'eqneditor') to TinyMCE or CKEditor but with no luck. I am following the steps found on their documentation page but with no lock. I tried all the techniques  but no matter what I do, the tinymce and ckeditor components can't see the plugin that I'm injecting. The problem is still there no matter what plugin I'm trying to add. It can only see a few default plugins.

Note: the tinymce and ckeditor plugins are added as ng2-tinymce and ng2-ckeditor.

Can I have an example of a proper way for adding a new plugin to one of those components on an Angular 4 project? 
I am using this ngx-admin template:

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The plugins for tinymce are separate from angular, once you copy the plugin files to the tinymce/plugins directory you need to add the plugin name to the plugins and toolbar list. For example

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: 'equationeditor',
  content_css: '/path/to/mathquill.css',
  toolbar: [
    'bold italic underline | bullist numlist | subscript superscript |     equationeditor'
  ],
});
```

I've updating an existing math formula editing plugin to work with the latest Tinymce 4, previous versions don't properly work with the latest versions of tinymce.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce_mobileequationeditor